# PCIe USB card on kernel 4.15

Tags: usb, kernel, pcie

I purchased a PCIe USB card PEXUSB3S44V from StarTech (link below). I use ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.15. I can see the card when typing lspci and lsusb. But it doesn't work. I contacted StarTech support and they tell me that this card doesn't work with kernels higher than 4.9. Do I have any way to fix this? Can I compile and run the kernel 4.9? Could this interfere with other softwares on this system? I only use CUDA and tensorflow on this system.

https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/PCI-Express-USB-3-Card-4-Dedicated-Channels-4-Port~PEXUSB3S44V#dnlds

Comment: original kernel version of 16.04 is 4.4 so I won't say it can't work.  But there's not guarentee that proprietary graphic driver will still work.

Comment: @AlvinLiang Agreed regarding the kernel version for the **original** 16.04 but I think 16.04.1 already comes with a +4.9 kernel. But in any case this is a USB3.0 card adapter. Is your comment about the proprietary graphics drivers because of CUDA? It depends on the Nvidia driver version, not so much on the kernel version.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yeah, you're right, I'm not familiar with proprietary drivers so I don't know if there's any dependency thing to be fixed.  Just I saw somebody complained about his graphic card stopped working after installing older kernel.  Anyways µPD720202 support is broken now, I would not bother to do a lot of work if I can replace it with another working one.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia So in your opinion as long as the graphics drivers are compatible with let's say kernel 4.9, I should be fine?

Comment: @baca Yes, if the drivers compile correctly for the kernel version, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I have been in touch with StarTech. They couldn't understand why the card isn't working on my computer. I tried it with another computer and it worked fine, under both kernels 4.15 and 4.9. So my problem doesn't seem to come from ubuntu.

Comment: I have been in touch with StarTech as well. It is a problem with the chip on these cards. Some Linux kernels don't have driver support. I am trying to find out more about this. I might have to buy something newer or from different vendor. Though, one needs to be careful not to buy a card with the same chips.